# Which of the following is true given that sets are subsets of $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: compactness, connectedness

Let $A,B,C$ be non-empty subsets of $\mathbb{R}^2$. Pick the correct statement(s) from below:

(A) If $B$ is compact, $C$ is open and $B \cup C$ is compact, then $B \cap C \ne \emptyset$.

(B) If $B$ and $C$ are path-connected and $B \cap C \ne \emptyset$ then $B \cup C$ is path-connected.

(C) If $B$ and $C$ are connected and open and $B \cap C \ne \emptyset$,then $B \cap C $ is connected.

(D) Let $A$ be a nonempty countable subset such that $|A| \ge 2$ then $A$ is not connected

I know that $D,B$ is true.

(A) is not true if we take $B=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : \|(x,y)\|=1 \}$ and $C = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : \|(x,y)\|<1 \}$ then $C$ is open and $B \cup C$ is compact but their intersection is empty.

(C) Assume that $C \cap B$ is not connected then we have an open and closed set $U$ which is a proper  subset of $B \cap C$. Then $U$ is both closed and open in $A$ and $U$ is both open and closed in $B$ . I don't think this logic is correct. Can someone drop some hints?

Comment: It should be $B\cap C \ne \emptyset$, not $B\cap C \ne \{\emptyset\}$

Comment: I think (B) is false, while (C) is true.

Comment: @HossienSahebjame Actually (B) is true and (C) is false

Comment: I thought intersecting connected sets have a connected union?

Comment: oh my fault, sorry It says the intersection, I thought it said union.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

D and B are indeed known theorems / propositions and your counter-example for A is correct. For C (it's false) you can come up with a counter-example. We know that the intersection must be open, so start with a disconnected open set - let's say two disjoint open balls. Call this set $ D $. Can you think of two connected open sets $ B $ and $ C $ such that $ D = B \cap C $? See the image below for what I have in mind.

> [image]
>
>
>  $B$ is the interior of the union of the two disks and the green strip. $ C $ is the interior of the union of the two disks and the red strip.

Comment: How did you understand that $C$ is false?

Comment: I drew a counter-example. I could add it to the answer, but I think you will be able to find it on your own. Start by drawing a disconnected open set ($B \cap C$) and from there try to find suitable sets $ B $ and $ C $.

Comment: Aren't we suppose to assume that the intersection of $B$ and $C$ has to be nonempty? I can't come up with such $B$ and $C$

Comment: For a counterexample to (C) consider a capital letter D. Can you see two connected subsets (one a straight line segment, the other a curved line) whose intersection just consists of 2 points?

Comment: How come the straight line is open in $R^2$?

Comment: It is not, but think of the D with a very thick line and consider the interior of that line

Comment: @ThirstForMaths I edited my answer to include a picture of what I had in mind.

Comment: @shortmanikos the green and the red straight lines are like a strip and we are considering the interior of the strip right?

Comment: @ThirstForMaths yes